# Propagation of setState changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-16

I have an React application that has the following structure:

component **A** is composed of **B** and **C**

If I call `setState` in component **B**, will component **A** and **C** be also notified (meaning they will also re-render at least enter reconciliation phase)?

Comment: No. if you change state of component **A** then **B** & **C** will be re-rendered because component **A** render function will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

the setState only update the state of the component, causing a re-rendering of this component (and so all of its child components). If B has no child, it will only re-render B.
You can learn more about the lifecycle of component [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).
There is a way though to trigger something in the parent component but is this what you want? If yes, I can tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing doing setState in componentWillMount won't trigger re-rendering because componentWillMount is invoked before your component renders. This principle applies to all parent and child components.